# Collapse floated children in parent

Tags: css

I have child elements in wrapper div which I would like to float to new line when height of the parent get smaller than wrapper div:

http://jsfiddle.net/vm57t/207/

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
   position:relative;
   top:5px;
   left:5px;
   width:30px;
   background:green;
   overflow:auto;   
}

.child{
   position:relative;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   background: #ccc;
   margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

Like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then when window size gets smaller they start making new column to the right:

```
1 4
2
3
```

Comment: collapse where/how? can you add picture of how you want them to look like collapsed?

Comment: Is this roughly what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/vm57t/208/ (resize the window)

Comment: When you resize the window height to smaller, I want for children to start floating to new line to the right.

Comment: @Toniq im not sure, but i think you have to involve javascript for that

Comment: @ jcuenod Yes, but I need this layout vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: @Toniq so you're worried about losing vertical space - not horizontal space?

Comment: I have edited the post, you can see example how they have to behave. They must not get out of the provided space vertically.

Answer (score 1):

How about using columns?

```
column-count: 2; /* or 3 or whatever */
column-fill: auto;
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pMbtk/952/

Comment: I cant have multiple columns if all elements fit in single column. Plus it needs to work on all browsers. (ie8+)

Answer (score 1):

Column CSS is the hint, but without the column-count rule : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YXGYpV

```css
.child {
  background: gray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
  counter-reset: ulli;
  column-width: 30px;
  column-gap: 1px;
  -moz-column-width: 30px;
  -moz-column-gap: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.child:before {
  counter-increment: ulli;
  content: counter(ulli);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

To know wich browser can understand this : http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

If you want to include IE8, then you need [writing-mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPMRxR)

Answer (score 1):

One more solution - use **display: flex**. But it works only with modern browsers.

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/vm57t/212/

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is fine manual for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/